# HTTP Status 406 - The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses

Tags: spring, json, java, rest

Контроллер :

```
package blog.controller;

import blog.dao.CategoryDao;
import blog.domain.Category;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;


import java.util.List;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/rest")
public class ServiceController {

    @Autowired
    private CategoryDao categoryDao;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/categories")
    @ResponseBody
    public Category categories() {
        Category category = categoryDao.getAllCategories().get(0);

        return category ;
    }
}
```

Ответ сервера :

> HTTP Status 406 -
>
> type Status report
>
> message
>
> description The resource identified by this request is only capable of
>   generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to
>   the request "accept" headers.
>
> Apache Tomcat/8.0.8

В чем здесь проблема ?

Answer (score 2):

Гм, в описании ошибки, приведённом вами же, содержится ответ на ваш вопрос.

В запросе перечислены (в заголовке `Accept`) типы респонса, которые запрашивающая сторона хочет/может обработать, а контроллер возвращает другой mime-type. Вы можете исправить это добавив атрибут `produces` с нужным значением к аннотации `RequestMapping`.

Comment: Аннотации теперь выглядят так

    @RequestMapping(value = "/categories", produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public Category categories() {
        Category category = categoryDao.getAllCategories().get(0);

        return new Category();
    }

response code - 406

Comment: А в заголовке `Accept` клиентского запроса что содержится?

Answer (score 2):

Нужно добавить в зависимости Jackson.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.3</version>
</dependency>
```